# Calculate a closed workbook without opening it

Tags: openpyxl, xlwings

I try to use `xlwings` and `openpyxl` to work on workbooks. I am just wondering if it is always mandatory to open a workbook to manipulate it.

For example, is it possible to **recalculate** a closed workbook without opening it?

I tried `app_visible=False` of `xlwings`, it seems that it still launched Excel, and then made it invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to recalculate a closed workbook without opening it.

Comment: You mean, it is impossible in any library like xlwings, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils...?

Comment: It seems that we can write to a cell of a closed workbook without opening it by openpyxl, why is it impossible to calculate it without opening the workbook?

Comment: openpyxl "opens" the workbook just as much as any other application does. But it doesn't do formula evaluation.